# Tiered prices and product add ons in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am confronted with the following problem in woocommerce: we want to sell pens that can be printed to b2b customers. Prints are possible on the clip, the shaft and next to the clip. The prints can be made using 1,2,3 or 4 colors.

We have tiered prices for the pens and for the prints. For example: 1-200 pens cost 28 cent each, 201-500 pens cost 24 cent each, and so on. A one-colored print on the clip costs 13 cent when you choose 1-200 pens and 11 cent when you choose 201-500 pens. A two-colored print on the clip costs 26 cent when you choose 1-200 pens and 22 cent when you choose 201-500 pens. Same with the prints on the shaft and next to the clip.
It should be clear that a customer who buys 500 pens and wants a two-color print on the clip automatically needs to buy 500 2-color prints. He must not buy 500 pens and 200 prints!

For each print color and each area of print, e.g. clip, a template and installation fee is to be paid, regardless of whether the customer purchases 100 or 1000 pens. This is a one time production fee that is to be added to the total cost and separate from each individual pen's price. How can this problem be solved? Does somebody has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the variant product from WooCommerce feature. 
1-color is a variant with low price, 2 color is a variant with another price.

And then use the bulk discount to make 1-200, 201-500 to happen.
You can use the following plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-discount/

And do a little bit of code, if 2-color products are there in your cart add a fixed amount to each of those 2-colors bulk.

I think this will get your job done.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned the problem is that the customer can choose between a few possibilities. For example he can order a pen with 2 prints on the clip, 3 prints next to the clip and 4 prints on the shaft. So you have 4 tiered prices with 3 extra installation fees to add to the cart in one product. It's similar to a produkt bundle but i need to handle the prints on the pen like product options.

Comment: that's why I am suggesting you to add prints as variants

Comment: Thank you, i will try it next week!